# How does delayed expansion work in a batch script?

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

Take this simple series of commands executed in a batch environment:

```
>set ar[0]=orange
>set ar[1]=apple
>set ar[2]=banana
>for %i in (0,1,2) do echo !ar[%i]!
```

It outputs the following:

```
>echo !ar[0]!
!ar[0]!
>!ar[1]!
!ar[1]!
>!ar[2]!
!ar[2]!
```

So it obviously does not expand to its values. How would I do so?

Comment: Use `%` signs. Read `set /?` starting from _Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added_.

Answer (score 4):

**Sources:**
**Phase 5** in **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/8177207)**

**Delayed Expansion:** Only if delayed expansion is on, the command is not in a [parenthesized block on either side of a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053), and the command is not a ["naked" batch script](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7761) (script name without parentheses, CALL, command concatenation, or pipe).

- Each token for a command is parsed for delayed expansion independently.

  - Most commands parse two or more tokens - the command token, the arguments token, and each redirection destination token.
  - The FOR command parses the IN clause token only.
  - The IF command parses the comparison values only - either one or two, depending on the comparison operator.
- For each parsed token, first check if it contains any `!`. If not, then the token is not parsed - important for `^` characters.
  If the token does contain `!`, then scan each character from left to right:

  - If it is a caret (`^`) the next character has no special meaning, the caret itself is removed
  - If it is an exclamation mark, search for the next exclamation mark (carets are not observed anymore), expand to the value of the variable.

    - Consecutive opening `!` are collapsed into a single `!`
    - Any remaining unpaired `!` is removed
  - Expanding vars at this stage is "safe", because special characters are not detected anymore (even `<CR>` or `<LF>`)
  - *For a more complete explanation, read the 2nd half of this from dbenham
    [same thread - Exclamation Point Phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/1012053)*

**Phase 5.3) Pipe processing:** Only if commands are on either side of a pipe
Each side of the pipe is processed independently and asynchronously.

- If command is internal to cmd.exe, or it is a batch file, or if it is a parenthesized command block, then it is executed in a new cmd.exe thread via `%comspec% /S /D /c" commandBlock"`, so the command block gets a phase restart, but this time in command line mode.

  - If a parenthesized command block, then all `<LF>` with a command before and after are converted to `<space>&`. Other `<LF>` are stripped.
- This is the end of processing for the pipe commands.
- See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053 for more about pipe parsing and processing

**Phase 5.5) Execute Redirection:** Any redirection that was discovered in phase 2 is now executed.

- The results of phases 4 and 5 can impact the redirection that was discovered in phase 2.
- If the redirection fails, then the remainder of the command is aborted. [Note that failed redirection does not set ERRORLEVEL to 1 unless `||` is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10354016/1012053).

---

---

[image]

- You can also use the **`Delayed Expansion`** by **`cmd.exe`** with flag **`[/v:on | /v]`**, on the **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)** or in the **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** files.

[image]

- In your **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)** using **`cmd.exe /v:on /c`**

```bat
set ar[0]=orange
set ar[1]=apple
set ar[2]=banana
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe /v:on /C"echo !ar[%i]!
```

---

- In your **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file without declaring **`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`**, you can also use **`cmd.exe /v:on /c "command & command | command || command..."`**

```bat
@echo off 

set "ar[0]=orange" 
set "ar[1]=apple"
set "ar[2]=banana" 
for %%i in (0,1,2)do cmd /v /c "echo\ !ar[%%i]!"
```

---

- In your **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** declaring **`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`**:

```bat
@echo off 

set "ar[0]=orange"
set "ar[1]=apple"
set "ar[2]=banana" 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (0,1,2)do echo\ !ar[%%i]!

enndlocal
```

---

---

- Some layout variances for this **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** code:

```bat
@echo off 
set "ar[0]=orange" & set "ar[1]=apple" & set "ar[2]=banana" 
for %%i in (0,1,2)do %ComSpec% /v:on /c"echo !ar[%%i]!"
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

```bat
@echo off 
set "ar[0]=orange" & set "ar[1]=apple" & set "ar[2]=banana" 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && for %%i in (0,1,2)do echo\ !ar[%%i]!
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

```bat
@echo off 
set "ar[0]=orange" && set "ar[1]=apple" && set "ar[2]=banana" 
for %%i in (0,1,2)do <con: %ComSpec% /v:on /c"echo !ar[%%i]!"
call <con: rem./ && %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t -1 && endlocal
```

- You also can use **`call`** in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** or in your command-line to update this value:

```bat
set "ar[0]=orange"
set "ar[1]=apple"
set "ar[2]=banana" 
for %i in (0,1,2)do for %i in (0,1,2)do <con: call echo %ar[%i]%
```

---

---

- In your **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file or command line, all the following commands are the same, observing replacing **`%i`** with **`%%i`** in the case of use in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** files

```bat
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec% /v:on /r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec% /v:on /c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe /v:on /r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe /v:on /c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd /v:on /r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd /v:on /c "echo !ar[%i]!"


for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec% /v /r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec% /v /c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe /v /r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe /v /c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd /v /r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd /v /c "echo !ar[%i]!"


for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v:on/r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v:on/c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v:on/r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v:on/c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v:on/r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v:on/c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v/r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v/c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v/r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v/c "echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v/r "echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v/c "echo !ar[%i]!"


for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v:on/r"echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v:on/c"echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v:on/r"echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v:on/c"echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v:on/r"echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v:on/c"echo !ar[%i]!"


for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v/r"echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v/c"echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v/r"echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v/c"echo !ar[%i]!"

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v/r"echo !ar[%i]!"
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v/c"echo !ar[%i]!"


for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v/recho !ar[%i]!
for %i in (0,1,2) do %ComSpec%/v/cecho !ar[%i]!

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v/r"echo !ar[%i]!
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd.exe/v/c"echo !ar[%i]!

for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v/recho !ar[%i]!
for %i in (0,1,2) do cmd/v/cecho !ar[%i]!
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Why does call set work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893287/why-does-call-set-work-differently-in-a-cmd-windows-versus-a-cmd-file)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

  [√] **[Use parentheses/brackets to group expressions in a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)**

Answer (score 3):

Delayed expansion is mainly used to expand variable values more than one time, especially in For loops.

Quoting from https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion command.

> Variable expansion means replacing a variable (e.g. %windir%) with its value C:\WINDOWS

> By default expansion will happen just once, before each line is executed. The !delayed! expansion is performed each time the line is executed, or for each loop in a FOR looping command.
> First we look at this example:

```
set i=0
for /l %%a in (0,1,10) do (
  set /a i=%i%+1
  echo %i%
)
```

Here we expect this will output numbers 1 to 10. However, everytime it will output only 0. Because every time the variables are expanded one time, so values don't change.

This time we will try with delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set i=0
for /l %%a in (0,1,10) do (
  set /a i=!i!+1
  echo !i!
)
```

This time we will get the expected output, because each time we expand the values and the value gets changed.

Your code does not work because you have to add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at start of your code.

Hope that helps