# read in multi line text file and assign multi-named environment variables in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to read through a multi-line  text file like...

C:\Test.txt

Text file contains:

```
bof --------------------------------
This is line 1
  This is line 2
C:\util 
This is line 4
EOF --------------------------------
```

I can read in lines and echo them using this:

```
@For /F Tokens^=1*Delims^=]^ EOL^= %%A In ('Find /N /V ""^<"C:\test.txt"') Do @Echo(%%B&>Nul echo
```

**But**:

I would like to set env var(s) from within the loop as it goes, so I need to name and assign the value to them dynamically from within the loop.

Echoing to the screen is not actually needed for my purposes, just the assignments are.

How do I get to a point where I can do the following after the acquisition of the text lines?

```
Echo _var1=%_var1%
echo _var2=%_var2%
echo _var3=%_var3%
echo _var4=%_var4%
```

Thanks

Comment: not sure why but the CR were removed from my text and the lines are hard to separate now.  should be 4 lines of text in the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delayed expansion here:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & set i=0
@For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=] EOL=" %%A In ('Find /N /V ""^<"C:\test.txt"') Do (
   set /a i=i+1
   set "_var!i!=%%B"
)
```

Now here:

```
For /l %%a in (1,1,4) do echo _var%%a is !var%%a!
```

Will give:

```
_var1 is This is line 1
_var2 is   This is line 2
_var3 is C:\util
_var4 is This is line 4
```

Read more:

- [Batch file delayed expansion - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Batch file For /f loops - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [How Delayed Expansion works in batch file - SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1569594/how-does-delayed-expansion-works-in-batch-script)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I would like to reply with some code, but I guess I don't know the proper etiquette.  I tried entering it here but no CR allowed.  So I guess I'm supposed to answer my own question.  So here goes.

Comment: I deleted my feeble attempt to compact the code.  I was fooling myself.  The only change is adding the overlooked _ to the last for loop in the environment variable.  Thank you Wasif Hasan for your excellent answer,

Answer (score 1):

```all-bat
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f ^tokens^=*delims^= %%i in ('type test.txt'
)do set /a "_c+=1+0" && <con: set "_var!_c!=%%~i"

for /l %%l in (1 1 !_c!)do echo\_var%%l=!_var%%l!

%__AppDir__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto=:EOF
```

---

- **`test.txt`** file contents/layout:

```all-bat
This is line 1
  This is line 2
C:\dir
This is line 4
This is line 5
C:\util
This is line 7
C:\folder
This is line 9
```

---

- Outputs:

```all-bat
_var1=This is line 1
_var2=  This is line 2
_var3=C:\dir
_var4=This is line 4
_var5=This is line 5
_var6=C:\util
_var7=This is line 7
_var8=C:\folder
_var9=This is line 9
```

---

**1.** You do not need to use `"Tokens=1* Delims=] EOL="` to save/set all strings on your line to a variable, so it is unnecessary, use **`tokens^=*delims^=`**, this set tokens to all and reset/remove defaults delimiters.

```all-bat
... for /f ^tokens^=*delims^= %%i in (test.txt) ...
```

**2.** Increment a counter for your lines so that you can use a `for /L` loop dynamically and without having to edit it to manually add the number of lines in your file.

```all-bat
... set /a "_c+=1+0" ...
```

**Obs.:** When using this **`+=1+0`** in **`set /a "_c+=1+0"`**, you don't need to predefine your variable with **`set _c=0`**

**3.** Use an operator to immediately set the variable after the counter is incremented by storing the current line using that counter already incremented

```all-bat
... set /a "_c+=1+0" && <con: set "_var!_c!=%%~i" ...
```

**4.** For dynamic listing of your saved variables/lines, use as a limit of your loop **`for /L`** the total already saved in the variable **`!_C!`**, and to select them, just operate in a concatenation **`_var + %%l`**

```all-bat
for /l %%l in (1 1 !_c!)do echo\_var%%l=!_var%%l!
```

---

**Obs.: 5** If the first character in line is <kbd>**space**</kbd> or <kbd>**tab**</kbd> and you need to remove it, just remove delimiter:

```all-bat
for /f ^tokens^=*delims^= %%i in ('type test.txt')do ...
```

---

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd/d "%~dp0" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in (file.txt
)do set /a "_c+=1+0" && <con: set "_var!_c!=%%~i"

for /l %%l in (1 1 !_c!)do echo\_var%%l=!_var%%l!

%__AppDir__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto=:EOF
```

---

- **`file.txt`** file contents/layout:

```all-bat
This is line 1
TabThis is line 2
C:\dir
This is line 4
This is line 5
SpaceC:\util
This is line 7
C:\folder
This is line 9
```

---

- Outputs removing the first character from the line if it is the same as the standard delimiters:

```all-bat
_var1=This is line 1
_var2=This is line 2
_var3=C:\dir
_var4=This is line 4
_var5=This is line 5
_var6=C:\util
_var7=This is line 7
_var8=C:\folder
_var9=This is line 9
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Dir /?](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[For /L](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√]  **[Conditional Execution `||` and `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√]  **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: Wow.  That's a lot to digest.  Thanks for taking the time.