# Batch script to read from text file and create incrementing number for filenames

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch

I'm making a batch script where I download videos using ffmpeg.

First it needs to read download codes from a text file (*codes.txt*)

Then it checks the current directory if the same file exists, if it exists it increments a new filename.

Then it starts to download, however, I wasn't able to make these bunch of codes to work together.
(The incrementing method works but without the "read from txt file" code, if I combine the two it results to a blank filename. I think it's because the looping code is not compatible.)

Read (loop) from txt file code:

```
@echo off
set prefix=title-
set resolution=720p
set extension=mkv    
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (code.txt) do (
title Downloading "%prefix%.%extension%" @ %resolution%
"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -loglevel info -stats -i "https://somesite.com/%%A&quality=%resolution%" -i "https://somesite.com" -headers "Origin: https://somesite.come" -c copy -disposition:s:0 default -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "%prefix%.%extension%" 
pause
```

and using the incrementing method I found from [link](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/395079-Create-batch-file-for-ffmpeg-to-increment-the-file-output):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "ffmpeg=your_path_to\ffmpeg.exe"
SET "output_folder=D:\rendered_files"
SET "extension=mov"
SET "prefix=Scene_"

rem do not set this, just define it empty:
SET "output_path="

call :get_output_path "%output_folder%" %prefix% %extension%

rem here goes your ffmpeg command line where %1 is input file and "%output_path%" is your destination

"%ffmpeg%" -i %1 ..... your filters end such ..... "%output_path%"

echo Done
endlocal & echo press any key to exit ... & pause>nul & goto :eof



:get_output_path <output folder> <prefix> <extension>
SET "i=0"
SET "formated_value=000"
:loop
SET "output_path=%~1\%~2%formated_value%.%3"
if exist "%output_path%" call :increase& goto :loop 
goto :eof

:increase
SET /a "i=%i%+1"
SET "value=000000%i%"
SET "formated_value=%value:~-3%"
goto :eof
```

Combined batch script:

```
@echo on
echo.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set prefix=showabc-
set resolution=720p
set extension=mkv
SET "output_folder=%~dp0Downloads"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (code.txt) do (
SET "output_path="
call :get_output_path "%output_folder%" %prefix% %extension%
echo File "%prefix%%formated_value%.%extension%" will be saved at "%output_folder%".
title Downloading "%prefix%.%extension%" @ %resolution%
"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -loglevel info -stats -i "https://somesite.com/%%A&quality=%resolution%" -i "https://somesite.com" -headers "Origin: https://somesite.com" -c copy -disposition:s:0 default -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "%output_path%"
)
pause

:get_output_path <output folder> <prefix> <extension>
SET "i=1"
SET "formated_value=001"
:loop
SET "output_path=%~1\%~2%formated_value%.%3"
if exist "%output_path%" call :increase& goto :loop 
goto :eof
:increase
SET /a "i=%i%+1"
SET "value=000000%i%"
SET "formated_value=%value:~-3%"
goto :eof
```

This is the result I always get:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7FSa.png)

It's either ".mkv" or filename without incrementing numbers. :((

Sorry for the very long post. I hope someone can help me, thanks y'all! Stay safe!

Comment: You have delayed expansion enabled, but the counter appears to not use it. If I recall correctly, you will want to use `!` (the BANG char) instead of `%` (percent char) See for example: https://superuser.com/questions/1569594

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('type .\code.txt"')do call %:^) i "%%~a"

<con: rem./ & %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal & goto=:EOF

%:^)
<con: set /a "_%~1+=1+1000"
if exist "%~dp0downloads\showabc-!_%~1:~-3!.mkv" && goto %:^)

<con: title <nul && title downloading "showabc-!_i:~-3!.mkv" @ 720p  
echo\file "showabc-!_%~1:~-3!.mkv" will be saved at "%~dp0downloads".

"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -i "https://somesite.com/%~2&quality=720p" -i "https://somesite.com" ^
     -headers "origin: https://somesite.com" -c copy -disposition:s:0 default -bsf:a ^
     aac_adtstoasc -loglevel info -stats "%~dp0downloads\showabc-!_%~1:~-3!.mkv"
```

---

I'm sorry, but I removed your variables to try to understand your code and not make mistakes in applying them.

If I don't understand what you want to do, I hope you will signal me where I lost the north (plz) ...

The code below I will leave here as an attempt to help you, where in your future comments, with bigger and more accurate information, (me or other operators here), we can understand and propose a better solution for your case....

**Obs.: 1** We don't know the contents of your **`code.txt`** file

**Obs.: 2** I'm assuming your **[ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg)** commands are correct

**Obs.: 3** `Goto :EOF` goes straight to the **E**nd **o**f the **F**ile, and so, immediately ending the execution, inside your **`:label`**

**Obs.: 4** Use **`exit /b`** if you don't want to end the execution immediately, thus, your increment should work without premature interruptions ...